# Take input parameter and pass it throw asp-route-id in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core

```
 <input id="Find" class="form-control" />
            <input type="submit" value="Find" class="btn btn-primary" asp-action="Find" asp-controller="Order" asp-route-id="1" />
```

. I want to take a input and pass it to  asp-route-id
 Like asp-route-id=inputValue which is given by client

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<form  method="get">
    <input id="Find" class="form-control" name="Id" />
    <input type="submit" value="Find" class="btn btn-primary" asp-controller="Order" asp-action="Find" />
</form>
```